# running C exec in php background

Tags: php, c, raspberry-pi, exec, background-process

I have searched and found some suggestions to my question but almost all of them are executing php files, so i don't know if that has something to do with it not working for me.

My goal is for my webpage to load completely without finishing my script that takes x amount of time, but it wont do it with this line of code. Is there something im missing? i have seen this answer in many places and it seems to work for them.

```
<?php

exec("sudo ./EscalonVel 50 2 100 10 20 &> /dev/null &");
echo "Hello";
?>
```

Comment: Try `gpio write 28 0 &`. Although I don't see why do you want to do this!

Comment: i even tried commenting it out, no luck

Comment: It seems that you are implementing the wrong solution. What does the script do?

Comment: the script make a bunch of calculations and inserts data into a DB, the goal is to be able to graph this data in the page, but for that i need to first run this on the background

Comment: Is this command in the sudoers file? Or is `sudo` asking you for password? And why `sudo`, that doesn't seem right either. Did you know that you can write a [tag:c] function and call it from [tag:php], or an apache handler that hadles this too.

Comment: its on the sudoers, had to add `www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` to it

Comment: It does run the script, that i can be sure

Comment: it does run the code, that sample code does run it correctly but it won't do it on the background, it will wait for it to finish and then echo "Hello"

Comment: Why don't you use AJAX instead? Just load your page, write simple javascript that would ask the server to start the script and it will do what you want. For example a *php* script with the `exec()` line, and just use a simple `GET` request with AJAX.

Comment: Ill try ajax, and how can you do the apache handler to to this? might do the trick more effective

Comment: Ineed, the apache handler requieres an apache module if you can write [tag:c] or [tag:perl] code, and then setup the handler in the *apache2.conf* (assuming you have a .deb distro, which you apparently have). The *libphp5.so* is an apache module with a handler for *.php* files. Writing a PHP module could work too, you would do it in [tag:c] and use `fork()`. But I think the AJAX approach will be just fine. I am really curious about what the script does that takes so long.

Comment: the script is intended to take long, it is interacting with some motors and sending signals to them and it maxe to test them out, and at the same time im getting that data into mysql and i want to show this graph in the page by just selecting the data from mysql at the same time they are being generated

Comment: You might want a websocket for that to make it really real time.

Answer (score 0):

If you has to show on the page data calculated on the C script, then "someone" has to wait until it's finished to show it out. If the data comes directly from the command executed (output/stdout of the execution), then you cannot background the command with `&`: the output might come after request is dispatched, and process backgrounding disconnects it's output from actual execution. So you have 2 options:

1. Show the page "template" completely and prepare it to accept the contents at the very end of your HTML (suboptimal but possible)
2. Do a 2 request page: the first shows the template (full page) and the second (AJAX) fills it up with data from command execution. Depending on how you write it, the AJAX can do several request until the command is terminated, which is preferable if the script runs for more than 20 seconds. Then you'll need some kind of process checking and some backend to save (by command) and view (by AJAX request) the data, as a file or database.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thx, might not have explained myself completly, the background proccess is inserting some lines into a mysql DB so my approach is to call the script and afterwards start to refresh data in the page with the data from the DB.

Comment: Then, you need to do AJAX calls to check if process has finished. Depending in process execution time, those calls may be 10 seconds from the next, or they may be 10 minutes. If the process has not finished, then call another AJAX request in X seconds (with `setTimeout`). If it did, then present data. I don't know which data it is. It might be good with JSON, JavaScript or plain HTML. Its up to you and your needs.

Comment: There is no such thing as a [tag:c] script.